# Uncertain on how to get an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Alrighty.

So my problem is quite simple I believe, but for some reason I can't seem to figure it out.

I want a user to be able to request a tour booking. Then get the user_id and the tour_id for which it's requesting the tour. I am successfully able to get the user_id, but not sure how to get the tour_id.

Here's how my controller looks:

```
class TourRequestsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @tour_request = current_user.tour_requests.new(tour_request_params)
    if @tour_request.save
      flash[:success] = "You've requested a tour booking"
      redirect_to :back
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Unable to request a tour'
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end

  private 

  def tour_request_params
    params.require(:tour_request).permit(:tour_id, :user_id, :date)
  end
end
```

as you can see the user_id is obtained through current_user. I've tried adding a merge like such:

```
tour_request_params(tour_id => Tour.id / @tour.id / tour_path(tour.id)
```

etc but it doesn't work. I know that I could add a hidden html field, however I want to make it as secure as possible, so you can't tamper with data.

The associations are that tours belongs to user, and user has many tours.

You can request a tour through tours/show the form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for TourRequest.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :date, id: 'datetimepicker', autocomplete: 'off', placeholder: 'dd.mm.yyyy' %>
  <%= f.submit 'Request a tour', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

How would I make it so that when I submit the tour booking request it gets the tour id?

Comment: You can *always* tamper with any data given to, or received from, the client layer. That's why in addition to authentication you always need authorization.

Answer (score 0):

You have 1 of 2 options:

1. Pass the tour ID to the controller each as a form attribute or as a param on the route
2. Save the tour ID in the session within the controller action that renders the tour request form

With either case, you are going to need to pass the tour ID to the server from the client side at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I think the id should be available, ie non-nil right after the save.

```
  def create
    @tour_request = current_user.tour_requests.new(tour_request_params)
    puts "id = #{@tour_request.id}"  # should be nil
    if @tour_request.save
      puts "id = #{@tour_request.id}"  # should be non-nil
      flash[:success] = "You've requested a tour booking"
      redirect_to :back
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Unable to request a tour'
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end
```